# bluetooth app instant crashes in activity

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

im new on this page and i need help with my app, i want to send data via bluetooth to an ESP32 wifi/bluetooth module, but when i enter on this activity (Habitacion 1) my app then tries to start a connection and crashes and i dont know why exactly: the problem goes on ConnectBT(). If you can help me, I would be grateful, thank you.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Habitacion1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    ToggleButton luzh2, puertah1, persianah1, tomabuttonh1;
    String address = null;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private boolean isBtConnected = false;
    static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_habitacion1);
        Intent newint = getIntent();
        address = newint.getStringExtra(bluetoothList.EXTRA_ADDRESS);//Recibo las direcciones MAC de la otra activity
        final ToggleButton luzh1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.luzh1);
        luzh2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.luzh2);
        puertah1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.puertah1);
        persianah1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.persianah1);
        tomabuttonh1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tomabuttonh1);
        new ConnectedBT().execute();
        luzh1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    luz1OnH1();
                } else {
                    if (btSocket != null) {
                        try {
                            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("Offl1H1".toString().getBytes());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            msg("Error");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        luzh2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    luz2OnH1();
                } else {
                    if (btSocket != null) {
                        try {
                            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("Offl2H1".toString().getBytes());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            msg("Error");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        puertah1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    puerta1OnH1();
                }else{
                    if(btSocket!=null){
                        try{
                            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("Offp1H2".toString().getBytes());
                        }catch (IOException e){
                            msg("Error");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        persianah1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    persiana1OnH1();
                }else{
                    if(btSocket!=null){
                        try{
                            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("Offpa1H1".toString().getBytes());
                        }catch (IOException e){
                            msg("Error");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private class ConnectedBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private boolean ConnectSuccess = true;//si llego aca esta casi listo
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(Habitacion1.this, "conectando...", "Por favor, espere");//muestra el dialogo del progreso
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)//mientras se muestra el dialogo de conexion, esta se hace en segundo plano
        {
            try {
             //  if (btSocket == null || !isBtConnected) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();                 //obtiene el dispositivo bluetooth
                    BluetoothDevice dispositivo = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);//Conecta con la direccion del dispositivo y comprueba si esta disponible
                    btSocket = dispositivo.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);//Crea la conexion rfcomm (spp)
                    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                    btSocket.connect();//comienza la conexion
               // }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                ConnectSuccess = false; //si la conexion falla el valor de la variable cambia a false
                msg("error");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)//despues de la conexion a segundo plano checkea si fue bien
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (!ConnectSuccess) {
                msg("Conexion Fallida, si es un dispositivo SSP intentelo de nuevo");
                finish();
            } else {
                msg("Conexion exitosa");
                isBtConnected = true;
            }
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    }private void msg(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    private void luz1OnH1() {
        if (btSocket != null) {
            try {
                btSocket.getOutputStream().write("Ol1H1".toString().getBytes());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"AASSAS",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                msg("Error");
            }
        }
    }
    private void luz2OnH1() {
        if (btSocket != null) {
            try {
                btSocket.getOutputStream().write("Ol2H1".toString().getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                msg("Error");
            }
        }
    }
    private void puerta1OnH1(){
        if(btSocket!=null){
            try{
                btSocket.getOutputStream().write("Offp1H1".toString().getBytes());
            }catch(IOException e){
                msg("Error");
            }
        }
    }
    private void persiana1OnH1(){
        if(btSocket!=null){
            try{
                btSocket.getOutputStream().write("Offpa1H1".toString().getBytes());
            }catch(IOException e){
                msg("Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```